# Is there a way to make sure I don't miss an emitted event?

Tags: web3js, contract-development, events

I'm trying to listen for Transfer events emitted by an ERC721 contract. I have tried using infura as a provider but it does have some problems and I can easily miss some events (which is crucial not to in my app). I've been recommended alchemyweb3 which is nicely optimized for this but the docs says, in really rare cases I might miss some. Does anyone have some insights on this? Would be much appriciated!